# PhantomJS status 'fail' for CSS file

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am getting Status=fail when requesting this CSS file

PhantomJS version = 2.0.0
Link : http://www.nfm.com/Content/MainMasterCss_C4BA203F2F5805AA4E787B1466B7F298.css

Even debugging not helping much.

```
console.log('Loading a web page');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://www.nfm.com/Content/MainMasterCss_C4BA203F2F5805AA4E787B1466B7F298.css';
page.open(url, function (status) {

    console.log(status);

    page.render('sample.jpg');

    phantom.exit();
});
```

I am actually trying to load an HTML page which has this CSS, 0KB JPG is generated if I make absolute path for that CSS. No resourceError is thrown for this CSS.

Answer (score 2):

PhantomJS doesn't support any content except HTML (XML). You can't open non-HTML page directly.

We have following issues to track this bug:

- https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11501
- https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10695

Comment: I am actually, loading a html source file and generating JPG, this CSS request makes 0KB JPG, no resourceError.id is generated for this CSS request aswell.

Comment: @YogeshUnavane Are you trying to open this CSS file directly via `page.open` or you are trying to load HTML page, which has this CSS file?

Comment: I am actually trying to load an HTML page which has this CSS, 0KB JPG is generated if I make absolute path for that CSS. No resourceError is thrown for this CSS. This CSS is needed for proper render.